# Marriage as visitor in Denmark

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, filipino-citizens, proof-of-ties

My and my fiancé are wanting to elope in Denmark, he's English and I'm Filipino.  In order to get there I need to get a Schengen visa but I'm uncertain about my eligibility.  I'm currently unemployed, not in education and have little savings. My fiancé has about £3000 in savings, to support the trip. Additionally I don't have a referee within the schengen area.  I'm worried about getting rejected as I don't want to waste any money or have flags against my name.  Based on this information is there anyway that I'd be able to be granted a visa, or is it not worth the time/money? Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Even if you had a visa, both you and your english fiancé probably don't fulfill the **Worthy purposes** conditions listed here: [Persons resident in countries outside of Denmark - Worthy purposes of entry into Denmark](https://en.coronasmitte.dk/rules-and-regulations/entry-into-denmark/persons-resident-in-countries-outside-of-denmark). This is basically true for the whole Schengen Area. So I would say `it not worth the time/money`.

Comment: Can you clarify what timeframe you are considering? As @MarkJohnson said, at the moment you won't be able to enter most of the Schengen Area due to Covid-related restrictions, but of course those won't last forever (hopefully!), which will then turn the question back to a "regular" visa question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the the replies. We understand that access to the country is currently restricted and we are planning to go ahead once the boarders reopen apologies for not clarifying that. We just don't want to pin our hopes on it if the visa will be declined.

Comment: Questions that you will probably need to answer are going to include "Where are you going to live after the wedding?" and "Why do you want to be married in Denmark?"

Comment: Thanks for the heads up DJ! I would never of thought about that :)